# Change the checkbox in UWP/XAML to show a cross when false

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Thank you in advance for your help. I want to change the style of a checkbox in my C#/UWP/XAML application to show a cross when false. The tickmark is fine when true. See pictures below. The first picture is what I want and the second picture is the way it is right now. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!!!

[image: This is what I want]

[image: This is what it is right now]

Comment: Hello @CoCalceDew, I tried the solution but it did not work.

Comment: Hi @VivekVerma, Very strange, It woks in my side. I will share my code sample.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks!

Comment: This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/CustomCheckBoxTest.git) please check.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I will. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I tried downloading the sample you provided and I get the same results as I did before. Clicking the checkbox does not do anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

For your requirement, you could custom CheckBox `Template`, And modify  the check shape for each state. then edit their Opacity in `VisualStateManager`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate1" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="TickMark.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="CheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="Transparent" Height="20" Width="20" 
               Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" 
               StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" 
               UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
            <!-- Create an X to indicate that the CheckBox is un-selected. -->
            <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" 
              Data="M103,240 L111,240 119,248 127,240 135,240 123,252 135,264 127,264 119,257 111,264 103,264 114,252 z" 
              Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" 
              FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
              Height="14" Width="16" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <!-- Create an V to indicate that the CheckBox is selected. -->
            <Path x:Name="TickMark" Data="M0,4 5,9 9,0 4,5" 
                  Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                  Height="14" Width="16" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill"/>

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                         Margin="10"
                      Grid.Column="1" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage**

```
 <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate1}" />
```

[image]